# Discussion in Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Solve the ordinary differential equation of the first order (using nonexact):
$$
3(y^4+1)dx+4xy^3dy=0
$$
I tryed but some mistakes were performed:
$$
3(y^4+1)dx+4xy^3dy=0,
$$
$$
3(y^{4}+1)dx=-4xy^{3}dy,
$$
$$
-\frac{3}{4}\cdot\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{y^{3}dy}{(y^{4}+1)}.
$$
Help to solve this equation.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @José Carlos Santos, Respected Mr. Santos, please, don't close this theme. I have solved the provided equation and published the solution here. Thank You!

Comment: I have voted to reopen it.

Answer (score 1):

$$
3(y^4+1)dx+4xy^3dy=0,\iff{3(y^{4}+1)dx}=-4{x}{y^{3}}{dy},\iff
$$
$$
\iff{-}\frac{3}{4}\cdot\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{{y^{3}}dy}{(y^{4}+1)},\iff{-}\frac{3}{4}\int\frac{dx}{x}=\int\frac{{y^{3}}dy}{(y^{4}+1)},
$$
From the **left part** we can receive:
$$
{-}\frac{3}{4}\int\frac{dx}{x}={-}\frac{3}{4}\ln{|x|}+C.
$$
From the **right part** we can receive:
$$
\int\frac{{y^{3}}dy}{(y^{4}+1)}=\int\frac{d({y^{4}+1})}{4(y^{4}+1)}.
$$
In the **right part** we will make a substitution:
$$
\bbox[lightgreen]
{
t=(y^{4}+1),
}
\implies\int\frac{d({y^{4}+1})}{4(y^{4}+1)},\iff\int\frac{dt}{4t}=\frac{1}{4}{\ln{|t|}},\implies\int\frac{d({y^{4}+1})}{4(y^{4}+1)}=\frac{1}{4}{\ln{(y^{4}+1)}}+C.
$$
Therefore
$$
\frac{1}{4}{\ln{(y^{4}+1)}}={-}\frac{3}{4}\ln{|x|},
\\
{\ln{(y^{4}+1)}}={-3}\ln{|x|},
\\
(y^{4}+1)=x^{-3},
\\
\bbox[lightgreen]
{
y=\left(x^{-3}-1\right)^{\frac{1}{4}}+C,
}
$$

Good luck!